# Can't fork my own query in data explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

When you like some query and you want to make a new fork of it and modify it, it's easy when the query is not yours! You just click the "fork query" and that's it.

But if you have your own query, the only possibility offered is "edit query", which will rewrite the old one! You cannot fork any more! You have to compose new query and then copy everything, title, description, code, and make it favorite again...

Could we have the fork also for our queries? The *fork operation is already present*, just make it available and that's it. The user interface would also be much more consistent.