# Organize queries on Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

On Data.SE, I tend to write a bunch of different queries, usually when something piques my interest and I want to look at a particular subset of the data.  I currently have four pages of queries that I've written over time, quite a few that I'm no longer interested in keeping, and more that are only for specific sites.  Currently, there's no way to organize them, delete them, or anything other than giving them a name or marking them as favorite.

Comment: I looked as best as I could and didn't' find anything in particular that shared the same topic, other than someone wanting a tagging system: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93819/add-tags-to-categorize-the-queries-on-sede

Comment: for everything you describe there is dupe I think: [delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122324/delete-own-query-on-data-explorer), [collapse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134928/collapse-data-explorer-queries-to-only-show-latest-revision), [Fork own query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214254/cant-fork-my-own-query-in-data-explorer). Do know that SEDE is open source. The community should implement features and then provide pull requests.

Comment: @rene I didn't know it's open source

Comment: I put them in text files with names like "fixCSEvoting" or "dostuff" and save them in a directory named "tools". I actually wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: @Shog9 you forgot "doMoreStuff".

Comment: I admit it is a bit hidden @DForck42 but the github repo is [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer)